# Cant Find my Axis2 Web Service deployed on OpenShift

Tags: web-services, jakarta-ee, tomcat7, apache-axis, openshift

I deployed a web service developed using `Apache Axis2` on `Openshift`.
When I try accessing the axis2 `index.jsp`, I can see the index page which only contains the default Version.

**Q:**
How do I get to display the web service other web services I created as I can view them on my localhost through the browser in Eclipse?

I have done a few searches online and seen some suggestions as to making adjustments to `axis2.xml`. In that regard, I have tried changing the contextRoot parameter and the servicePath without no success though I am not too sure if I am making the right changes.

My project structure in Eclipse is shown below:

```
SieveService
+...
+Java Resources
++src
+++Model
++++some model classes
+++Services
++++SieveServiceService.java
++Libraries
+...
+WebContent
++axis2-web
+++...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem and that's occurs because openshift's tomcat server only deploys services in aar format, meanwhile in localhost deploys aar and exploded files too.

You need to create a aar file with your services and put it into your WebContent/WEB-INF/services/ directory. You need to update the services.list file too with the name of your services.

After that you must see your services in your openshift server.